# Why SELECT-INSERT request is so long?

Tags: mysql, lamp

I have **LAMP** server with fast storage and a lot of memory and processor power.

There are 2 tables with same structure, one with 30.000.000 records, other is empty.
I want to copy data from first table to second and use this request:

```
 INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 ;
```

This request need more then 4 hours to complete. I think this is not normal because `mysqldump` of `entire database finishes less then hour`.

Are there any limits to `SELECT` request? Or I must use other code to `optimize performance`?

Comment: `INSERT` is usually slower than `SELECT`. Three times slower seems a bit too much, but I wouldn't rule it out. How much time does it take to import the dump that takes you a hour to dump? You might want to [disable constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) for the duration of the `INSERT...SELECT`.

Comment: Are there any triggers that run on INSERT into table2?

Comment: With an import, the data can be read in bulk from the source. Via SELECT/INSERT, it will have to read a record, then write it, and continue on for each of the 30million rows. It's gonna take a while.  Setting the readahead buffer of the OS and database may help significantly, by reading more at a time, so reducing disk-head movements.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this. Also i will think about optimizations from here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-myisam-bulk-data-loading.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the schema is as like as the first table, then give the order of values in **Insert query**. ***** lowers the performance of the **Select query**, And **NoLock** Increase the data availability

like,

```
Begin Tran
      INSERT INTO (Col1,Col2, Col3,...Coln) table2 
    SELECT (Col1,Col2, Col3,...Coln) FROM table1 with (NoLock)
Commit
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably down to housekeeping tasks such as indexing the data and allocating storage space.

Answer (score 0):

30 million is a lot. you query in bits, like 100 - 1000 results in each query.

or

I would advice you to use phpmyadmin in the operations area (select the source table 1st), you would see copy table.

or

if you are copying across different locations, use mysqlworkbench to export and import in the new table. hope this helps.

Comment: 30 million is a small number of records. It is the size of the records that matter. If one record is 1 MB big then that is going to be 30 000 000 megabytes. Or 30Gb of data to write.

Answer (score 0):

When adding more than a few thousand records,  especially if the table you are writing to is not in use.  Turn off indexes while adding and turn them back on afterwards.  If you have more than one index do them all.

ALTER TABLE `table_name` DISABLE KEYS;

import your data and turn them back on.

ALTER TABLE `table_name` ENABLE KEYS;

For more details see http://support.tigertech.net/mysql-large-inserts